# How can a 2D Hadamard delta function be represented as a matrix?

Tags: matrices, matlab, dirac-delta

I have been shown the following Hadamard delta function to be represented as a 2D array:

$$\delta_H (u,v) = \begin{cases}
1 & u=u_0\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,v=v_0 \tag{2}\\ 0 &\mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

In my understanding, *u* represents the x-axis and *v* the y-axis and $(u_0, v_0) = (3,3)$ (central), so  unless I am reading this incorrectly, in my head if we had a 6 x 6 matrix, it would look like:

$$\begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 \end{matrix}$$

This does not look right for me, as the matrix would always look the same independetly of the matrices being used. In the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790580/how-to-define-a-2d-discrete-delta-function-that-can-take-array-input-in-matlab) the matrices produced via MATLAB code, do not look like this, but I don't understand why their is different.

How should the delta function be represented like "matrixwise".

---

This is based on :

[Hadamard single-pixel imaging versus Fourier single-pixel imaging (2017) by Z. Zhang](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-25-16-19619&id=370424)

Comment: That isn’t a Dirac delta function, because the delta function takes an infinite value at the point. (Dirac delta functions are technically not functions, but distributions.)

Comment: My mistake, it is a Hadamard delta function. Thank you.